# ui-router with angular translate

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-translate

I'm using angular translate with ui router. In my en.json file I have something like

```
"test-text-url": "I am <a ui-sref=\"my.state\">here</a>"
```

But when I load the site with that translation verbiage, I only see an anchor tag without the href or ui-sref. So basically just

```
I am <a>here</a>
```

If anyone knows how to fix this, that would be awesome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) and [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce). `$sce.trustAsHtml` allows you to say that the string you have can be trusted and used for `ng-bind-html` which would you use in your template. The reason these exist is to prevent xss (chross site scripting)

Comment: How can I use this with angular bootstrap tooltips? Im using  ui-tooltip-html so I cant use ng-bind-html. So it looks like `uib-tooltip-html="'{{'test-text-url' | translate}}'"`